# How do I write TypeScript tests that don't include the classes under test in the transpiled test code?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, typescript

I have a TypeScript project that compiles down to a single JS file in /dist.

I have Jasmine tests, also written in TypeScript, that reference the various classes they test with references like:

```
/// <reference path="../../../src/script/classUnderTest.ts" />
```

When I compile the tests the TypeScript compiler pulls in all the referenced classes and I get a single JS file containing the test code and the code under test.

This actually works fine for just running the tests, but now I'd like code coverage too. From what I can tell, to get Istanbul to work I need to have the code under test separate from the test code. Also it would be nice to be testing exactly the JS file that will be live.

So, how can I get the type safety and autocomplete benefits of "/// reference" whilst using my compiled JS file when the tests are actually run?

(Or am I barking up the wrong tree entirely?)

Note, I am building this on a Mac, so from what I've read Chutzpah is not currently an option. I'm also currently using only npm scripts to do builds. I'd prefer to not bring in grunt or gulp unless it's absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So, how can I get the type safety and autocomplete benefits of "/// reference" whilst using my compiled JS file when the tests are actually run?

Don't using TypeScript's `--outFile` option ([few other reasons](https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/out.md)). Instead use modules e.g. `--module commonsjs` and a module loader e.g. `webpack`.

## More

Browser quickstart : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/quick/browser.html

Modules: 
https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/modules.html

Comment: Thanks, can you be a bit more specific? If I use a TypeScript import in my test file then building the tests rebuilds the main code (separately though so coverage does work). If I were to use something like RequireJS then I guess I wouldn't get the type safety unless I also created a .d.ts file for my compiled module?